# Быстрая обработка больших файлов

Tags: c#

Возможно ли в C# прочитать/загрузить файл в оперативную память и потом оттуда быстро его построчно прочитать?

Нужно читать, скажем, файлы, большие 4 GB.

Comment: А где вы столько оперативной памяти-то найдете?

Comment: @LorDo весь файл загружать в оперативную память не нужно, нужно из него кусками читать данные(например построчно).

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 8):

Если вы используете Net 4.0, то попробуйте использовать класс [MemoryMappedFile](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.io.memorymappedfiles.memorymappedfile(v=vs.110).aspx), предназначенный специально для чтения файлов больших размеров

Либо вариант использовать класс [StreamReader](https://www.google.ru/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0ahUKEwj7yYat2u7JAhXEXiwKHaWkCKQQFggbMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fru-ru%2Flibrary%2Fsystem.io.streamreader(v%3Dvs.110).aspx&usg=AFQjCNFZSTPb50B-xErPlx47nQfsRRG4dg&sig2=_FqZK7FH7bu8o1EjA8rgdA&bvm=bv.110151844,d.bGg&cad=rjt), построчно читаю из файла с помощью функции ReadLine

Можно использовать [LINQ](https://www.google.ru/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0ahUKEwih7Ouw3O7JAhXICywKHYEcCKsQFggbMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fru-ru%2Flibrary%2Fbb397926.aspx&usg=AFQjCNHH-GvOJWgcoOcRlCLNLhgcaUILKw&sig2=WMlW8jCD34ovtXQviiKZbA&bvm=bv.110151844,d.bGg&cad=rjt)

```
int result = File.ReadLines(filePath).Count();
```

Функция [File.ReadLines](https://www.google.ru/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0ahUKEwj-r-LV2-7JAhWGESwKHUrSCdIQFggbMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fru-ru%2Flibrary%2Fdd383503(v%3Dvs.110).aspx&usg=AFQjCNFgpGZQD_xIrPMNJlYiLXn9nUoHaw&sig2=L4QMGhbNHPPSwctLIYSBxg&bvm=bv.110151844,d.bGg&cad=rjt) будет возвращать IEnumerable < string>, который будет лениво загружать в память новую строку(то есть по требованию), и у вас не будет большая загрузка оперативной памяти. В переменной *result* будет содержаться общее количество строк в файле. Можно `Count()` убрать и просто в цикле читать построчно файл

```
foreach(var line in File.ReadLines(filePath))
{
     // line содержит прочитанную строку из файла(текущая строка загрузиться в память только в этот момент)
}
```

Comment: _"текущая строка загрузиться в память только в этот момент"_ -- точнее в памяти выделяется буфер и файл считывается блоками. из блока читается строка и возвращается из ReadLines

Comment: @Stack, спасибо за пояснение.